# To investigate the convergence of the improper integral: $\int _0^{+\infty }\:\frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2\sin^2x}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

To investigate the convergence of the improper integral: 
$$\int _0^{+\infty }\frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2\cdot \sin^2 x}$$

This is my last job. I can not cope, help, please.

Comment: @user.kos where did you get this problem from?

You can prove it convergens using the dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I responded back when he had the wrong problem in the question, which was an integral that converges. Nice solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it just

$$
\frac{x}{1+x^2}<\frac{x}{1+(x\sin(x))^2}
$$

and the fact that the integral

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{n}\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\infty
$$

is unbounded?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Why do you have removed the answer?

Comment: @user.kos: Because I do not like to be downvoted for nothing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So maybe your answer is incomplete?

Comment: My answer was perfectly fine, it proved that the integral is divergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i wanted to upvote your answer, and then it was gone ^^

Comment: @tired: thank you. I undelete it, your opinion is valuable to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio now someone downvoted me, that's life...ask me why^^

Comment: @tired: I think someone is having fun in a very silly way.

Answer (score 4):

It is not convergent, since over the interval $\left[k\pi-\frac{1}{k\pi},k\pi+\frac{1}{k\pi}\right]$ (for any $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$) the integrand function is greater than:
$$ \frac{k\pi-\frac{1}{k\pi}}{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{k\pi}\right)^2}, $$
since $\left|\sin(k\pi+\theta)\right|\leq |\theta|$, and the series
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{2\left(1-\frac{1}{k\pi}\right)}{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{k\pi}\right)^2}$$
is divergent, while the series is just a lower bound for the integral over
$$ \bigcup_{k\geq 1}\left[k\pi-\frac{1}{k\pi},k\pi+\frac{1}{k\pi}\right]\subset\mathbb{R}^+. $$

Comment: Can you please reply in detail painted, I do not quite understand?

Comment: @user.kos: try to plot that function and check it has many peaks near $\pi,2\pi,3\pi,4\pi,\ldots$. If every peak give a contribute to the integral that is around one and there are infinite peaks...

Comment: A downvote, really? Why? There is nothing wrong in the above lines. At most, this solution is an overkill.

Comment: the promised upvote (+1) . Interesting way to think about such a problem!